# basic string separation in php

Tags: php, string

I have an alphanumeric string like `1234and5678`.
I want to store the numbers preceding `and` i.e `1234` into one variable and the number after `and` i.e `5678` into another variable as shown below:

```
$var1=1234;
$var2=5678;
```

also what should  do if i replace `and` by some random special characters like `#$%` etc.

Can you please help me out? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: i've edited my answer according to your changes

Comment: thank you all for your suggestions...it helped me a lot! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = "1234and5678";
list($before, $after) = explode("and", $string);
```

This splits the string into two variables based on the delimeter ("and"), whatever is before and is saved in a variable called `$before`, whatever is after is saved into a variable called `$after`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `preg_split()` function, in your case: `$var = preg_split("/[\D]+/", "1234and5678");` That gives you `$var[0]` = '1234' and `$var[1]` = '5678'

According to you edit, you can:

1. replace regex on any another that you need (e.g. `$var = preg_split("/[\d]+/", "1234and5678");` for any non-numeric element)
2. use `preg_match_all("/(\d+)/","1234and5678", $var)` to find any numbers in your string

Answer (score 0):

Use split http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php with "and" as separator. That should give you an array with the two numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions. I provided a link for regexes in php. Split is deprecated as of version 5.3.0 and you should not rely on it.
[Perl compatible regular expressions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php)